# how to change access mail merge source?

Tags: ms-access

I have an expression that pulls a month and date from one field (date), and then pulls the year from another field (DOB - date of birth).

Example data from fields:

**Date: 1/2/2003**

**DOB: 1/15/1953**

**An expresson:**

```
Cancel Date: DatePart("m",[Date]) & "/" & DatePart("d",[Date]) & "/" & (DatePart("yyyy",[DOB])+60)
```

**which would return: 1/2/2013**

my problem is: If the DOB occurs after the existing DATE anniversary in that year, then the cancel date should increment 1 year, so the expression above should return 2014 instead.  How would I go about including that and simplifying this expression?  thanks!

Comment: no, it is only a query

Comment: Good.  Did my suggestion work?  I was unsure how many years to add when [Date] and [DOB] are the same month and day.

Comment: @HansUp working on it now. I am trying to write your answer in the expression builder, or is this incorrect? It tells me it is too complex

Comment: Can you do it from SQL View?  Design View is fine for simple expressions, but gets in my way when the expression is moderately complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
Cancel Date: DatePart("m", [Date]) & "/" & DatePart("d", [Date]) & "/" & (DatePart("yyyy", [DOB]) + IIf((DatePart("m", [DOB]) < DatePart("m", [Date])) Or (DatePart("m", [DOB]) = DatePart("m", [Date]) And DatePart("d", [DOB]) < DatePart("d", [Date])), 60, 61))
```

The `IIf()` part essentially says

```
If (Month([DOB]) < Month([Date]))
        Or (Month([DOB]) = Month([Date]) And Day([DOB]) < Day([Date])) Then
    add 60
Else
    add 61
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this query, so it may need tweaking to get what you want.  The idea is to use `Format()` to simplify the *m/d/* part.  Then use an `IIf()` expression to determine how many years to add to `Year([DOB])`.

```sql
SELECT
    Format([Date], 'm/d/') & (Year([DOB])
        + IIf(DatePart('y', [DOB]) > DatePart('y', [Date]), 61, 60))
        AS [Cancel Date]
FROM YourTable;
```

That approach relies on `DatePart('y', ...)`, which gives you the *"day of year"*.  For example, `DatePart("y", #2013-04-02#)` returns 92.  You can use this method to compare the month/day part of one date with that from another date ... sort of a short cut to avoid checking the month and day separately.

**Unfortunately**, `DatePart('y', ...)` doesn't account for leap years correctly.  (See Gord's comment below.)

Comment: +1 for a much more compact solution and for the "day of year" trick -- sneaky.... :)

Comment: Sneaky but darn useful in the right situations.  Those situations don't come around often, though, so I always have to track it down from online help.

Comment: ...just thinkin': Couldn't leap years trip up the "day of year" approach? `DatePart("y",#2012-03-01#)=61` but `DatePart("y",#1955-03-01#)=60`

Comment: @JasonBayldon Ahem ... check Gord's comment above.  Unfortunately, my suggestion is not leap-year-safe.  You should should use his answer instead.